Kernel keeps dying when importing Skimpy package
I installed skimpy package. However, anytime I import it or try to pip uninstall in my Jupyter Notebook, the kernel keeps dying. What should I do?
I tried to solve the problem in a Conda Env but it did not help. Also, I updated my Jupyter but did not change anything.
